# What is くらんたぁのクセして?

Tags: translation, meaning, slang

The following line is from the movie 仁義なき戦い. Near the beginning of the movie, a yakuza guy (上田) was collecting protection money on another guy's turf (土井). A moment later 土井 found this out and yelled:

「上田ァ!!われぇボンクラのくらんたぁのクセして、ここらのカスリ取っとるようなの!ここは元から土井のシマじゃ!!」

I have no idea how to parse "くらんたぁのクセして." Is this somehow a yakuza slang or Hiroshima dialect? (this scene took place in Kure city, Hiroshima by the way).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- ～のクセして is the same as ～のくせに explained [in this article](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=kuseni). くせして is less common.
- As for "くらんたぁ", this word is actually [愚連隊【ぐれんたい】](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%84%9A%E9%80%A3%E9%9A%8A) (a form of postwar street gangs) said with an accent ([source](http://jingi.hakata21.com/6-colum/1003wakasugi.html)). I don't know if it's in a real Hiroshima accent, though.
- われ in this context is vocative "you", or お前／貴様. It sounds very rough and offensive (at least to speakers of modern standard Japanese).

  > 《二人称の人代名詞》〔俗〕同等以下の相手をさげすんで指し示す語。おまえ。
  >   「━は年はいくつだ」[明鏡国語辞典 第二版]
- ボンクラ is just another derogatory word similar to "dummy" or "idiot".

われぇボンクラの愚連隊のクセして = "Yo, you're a damn 愚連隊 member and/but...".

Comment: ちなみに本編は Amazon Prime Videoで見られます（少なくとも今は）

Comment: Thanks! But could you explain what is ボンクラ in this context. My dictionary says ボンクラ ="(ぼんやり者〕 a stupid person; a blockhead;" so the first sentence seems to be "Even though we are stupid members of 愚連隊" but this doesn't sound right. (わりゃ = われ = we?)

Comment: @ChavLikit See the edit. This われ is a **second**-person pronoun.